# Redirect to specific application in IIS based on URL

Tags: .net, iis, config, redirect

Below is the structure of my IIS under Sites:

1. Default Web Site
   App1
   App2
   App3

I have got 3 URLs viz,

1. app1.mydomain.com
2. app2.mydomain.com
3. app3.mydomain.com

What i want is when user hits URL 1, it should redirect to App 1
when user hits URL 2, it should redirect to App 2
and so on..

I don't want to do it like this: app1.mydomain.com/App1

What is the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find an answer, I converted the "Applications" into "Websites"